# Why won't pinch to zoom work?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, meta-tags

I'm using the following meta tag but, frustratingly, pinch to zoom won't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Meta Tag as following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes" />
```

Comment: Try deleting the `width=device-width,height=device-height`. Also remove the `maximum-scale=10.0,minimum-scale=1.0`. Is it zoomable now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html 5 WebApp Scalability Meta Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427935/html-5-webapp-scalability-meta-tag)

Comment: you have to leave away "user-scalable=yes"

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt, that didn't work either :(

Comment: Removed user-scalable=yes - still won't work